# Setup for a Logback RollingFileAppender with prudent flag and a file location

Tags: logback

How can I craete a `RollingFileAppender` in Logback that accepts the prudent flag and also allows me to specifity the location of the log files?

I tried the following but as I understand from the documentation logback doesn't support the file property. Is there another way to set the log file location?

```
   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${MY_LOG_LOCATION_PROP}/logs/mylogfile.log</file>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>mylogfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `file` property is missing, the currently active log file will be inferred from the value of `fileNamePattern`. Thus, the `file` property is not mandatory. Just as importantly, in prudent mode it **must** be left blank.

Here is the relevant quote from the documentation on [fileNamePattern](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpFileNamePattern):

> Note that the file property in RollingFileAppender (the parent of
>   TimeBasedRollingPolicy) can be either set or omitted. By setting the
>   file property of the containing FileAppender, you can decouple the
>   location of the active log file and the location of the archived log
>   files. The current logs will be always targeted at the file specified
>   by the file property. It follows that the name of the currently active
>   log file will not change over time. However, if you choose to omit the
>   file property, then the active file will be computed anew for each
>   period based on the value of fileNamePattern. The examples below
>   should clarify this point...

Answer (score 3):

You can include the path in the fileNamePattern:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>/var/log/myapp/mylogfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>
```

Comment: Julien I think that you cannot add %i at TimeBasedRollingPolicy. You will get IllegalArgumentException at IntegerTokenConverter with information that logback cannot convert object to specific type.