# logback rolling file is misplaced

Tags: logback

I have an application that is deployed on OpenShift. I have the below configuration on log back.xml.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<prudent>true</prudent>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${logPath}myLogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
<encoder>
  <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{1}.%M - %m%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

I can read on the server $logPath is *properly* substituted and logback file has no problems in terms of setting properties. However it doesn't write the log file at the specified place. I tried this with specifying a file property and setting prudent to "false" as well, still no luck. I checked the permissions on the file system there are no problems, creating and writing a file at the specified location. I'm using log back 1.1.2.

Note: I checked this question and it's answer. [Setup for a Logback RollingFileAppender with prudent flag and a file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963723/setup-for-a-logback-rollingfileappender-with-prudent-flag-and-a-file-location)

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong here? I hope there isn't a bug with TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Updating ticket to clarify variable substitution (per logback documentation http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution )
${logPath} variable is substituted during build time (in jenkins) and the war file generated bears the correct path to the log file. Then this war file is deployed to Tomcat.

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps you are missing a separator character after the ${logPath} variable. So it would be: ${logPath}/myLogFile...

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I checked that, it's in place and not missing.

Comment: When you start your application, try setting [logback in debug mode](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting).

Comment: I already have <configuration debug="true">

Comment: I'm out of suggestions. Possibly offer a bounty on this question so someone with more experience can answer it?

Comment: I don't know if you solved the issue but I'm having the same. I'm starting to thinking that this may be due to the fact that my app is auto scaling, so the logs may be on another machine... I'll look more into this.